# navigator.globalization.getLocaleName phonegap globalization

Tags: angularjs, cordova, location, globalization

I am building an angularjs/phonegap app. using navigator.globalization.getLocaleName always returns 'en_GB' even though I am in Australia (and all devices where purchased in Australia).

```
navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
    function (locale) {
        alert('locale: ' + locale.value + '\n');
        console.log(locale);
    },
    function () {
        alert('Error getting locale\n');
    }
);
```

I have tried a few android devices and all are the same. I have read that this setting is build into the firmware on the device. is this correct or am I missing something from my settings?

Answer (score 0):

so I added the phonegap geolocation plugin and this is now working for me. I couldn't find any documentation on this!